# How can I maintain the current state of my EC2 instance after stopping it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

At the time of working with AWS, each time when I want to stop an EC2 instance, I lose all data. For example, when I try to ssh from one instance to another one, each time I have to copy the public key from the source instance to the target one. In particular, after stopping an instance, this data is delted in my target instance. I would like to know, is there any way to keep this data after stopping my instances?

Comment: You mean after temninating instance? Stopping instance does not delete your data, unless its instance-store based instance.

Comment: It's not clear what is it exactly that you want to achieve: saving instance-data outside of the instance can be achieved in many ways: saving the data in a DB, on S3, using EBS and there are probably additional options.

Comment: But, when I check the authorised_keys in the target machine, the key that I pasted from the public key in the source machine does not exit and I need to paste it again

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answer your question, I think hibernation process stores the in-memory state of the instance, along with its private and elastic IP addresses, allowing it to pick up exactly where it left off.
See the following example:[here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-hibernate-your-ec2-instances/)